# Which Eclipse IDE version to choose?

Tags: java, eclipse

How do I find which Eclipse version I have on my Ubuntu system?

This is what "About Eclipse SDK" says.

> Eclipse SDK
>
> Version: 3.5.2
>
> Build id: M20100211-1343

I am not sure if its the **Eclipse IDE for Java Developers** or the **Eclipse Classic version**.

What I would like to do is use Eclipse for

> Java based Web Application Development
>
> Ant Builds
>
> Deploy using Tomcat
>
> including HTML, CSS Editing

Please help me decide which version I should choose? I would like to upgrade my Eclipse setup from **whatever version it is now** to **a version that supports all the above**. Should I go for **Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers**?

Should I download **a totally new version from Eclipse site** or **can I just ADD necessary features/plugins to my current Eclipse setup**.

Please suggest.

Comment: Superuser.com/ubuntu.SE is where this belongs. Either way the eclipse packages for langauges are just eclipse with plugins/addons prepackaged.  You can add those on your own anyway.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> What I would like to do is use Eclipse for (...)

The **Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers** allows to do what you're asking for *out of the box*.

> Should I download a totally new version from Eclipse site or can I just ADD necessary features/plugins to my current Eclipse setup.

Both would work, although it would be simpler to just get directly the Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers (especially if you don't know exactly what plugin(s) you're looking for). Personally, I don't use the version you can get from the repository but download Eclipse from the official website and install it in [user mode](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EclipseIDE#User%20installation).

Answer (score 18):

See [Compare Eclipse Packages](https://eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php) for a nice chart

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Eclipse for only Enterprise Development, then as everybody has recommended I would use the Eclipse Java EE version. If you plan on occasionally using it for other development purposes then I would consider downloading a separate classic version as well.

The reason for this is that everybody is well aware of eclipse's plugin capabilities. Unfortunately, Eclipse can get bogged down with too many plugins or add on tools. What I have experienced is that if you are using it for Enterprise Development(J2EE) it might be a good idea to keep that as a separate environment then your other Java Development. That way you can download the plugins,tools,libraries,etc for your enterprise development, and you can use your classic version for any other development you might need.

The downside is you will have two versions, but this is not a problem granted you do not run them simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks CitadelCSAlum. That was really a very practical suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to play with Web development, then the Eclipse java EE for Developers is for you. It is shipped with components to make Java Enterprise applications to create Enterprise Applications (and bundle it in an Enterprise ARchiver, known as EAR file or Web ARchive, known as WAR file).

Answer (score 1):

The default Eclipse shipping with Ubuntu is the Classic version, and you can add more plugins.

I would recommend, however, to download th eJEE version manually and unzip it and run.  Then you have a local installation outside the system files.