# What's the difference between Eclipse Classic and Eclipse for Java Developers?

Tags: eclipse

I know that Eclipse for Java has the EGit plugin for Git repository access and comes with it's own Java compiler, but what other difference are there between the Java version and Classic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php you will notice Eclipse for Java has a few extras:

- EGit: http://www.eclipse.org/egit
- EMF: http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/
- GEF: http://www.eclipse.org/gef/
- JDT: http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/
- XML Tools: http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/
- Mylyn: http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/
- WindowBuilder: http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/
- Maven: http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/
- Eclipse Code Recommenders: http://eclipse.org/recommenders/

Basically, eclipse for Java includes quite a few useful additions as as the Window Builder which is a design tool for GUIs. If you download the classic distro you can download the additional options but it is much more limited.

See also:

[Which Eclipse IDE version to choose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960185/which-eclipse-ide-version-to-choose)

[What is the difference between Eclipse for Java (EE) Developers and Eclipse Classic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213712/what-is-the-difference-between-eclipse-for-java-ee-developers-and-eclipse-clas)